# Paypal not returning CUSTOM field variable as post data

Tags: php, paypal

I have a paypal form where I have a custom and CatDescription field. But

From

```
<form name="paypalForm" action="paypal.php" method="post" id="paypalform">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="shubhamjha900@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="CatDescription">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo md5(date("Y-m-d:").rand()); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="payment" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now">
</form>
```

The problem is that on my IPN page when the post data are sent back they send all the data but not the custom and CatDescription field data. Please tell me what can be the issue and how can I solve it. Can I use any other field by which I can send data? Whatever be the solution please help me.

Comment: Tested locallly, works well even if `CatDescription` and `custom` are left empty, like in your code (no "value" set). What's your problem exactly?

Comment: well sorry about that.. I am passing the data through jQuery here.. well.. it has data when the form Pay Now button is clicked.. but after payment it doesn't return the data.

Comment: But who dosen't return the data? Paypal server?

Comment: Have you tried to add `value=""` to incriminated fields in your form?

Comment: @paradise yes.. paypal server doesn't return custom field data as post data..

Comment: Oh yes I figured out the solution.. thanks for your time all of you :)